# Facebook comments plugin return an error "Object Invalid Value"

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-comments

I integrate facebook comments plugin inmy website. If in any page facebook comments are only '0' then it will return an error in popup 
error: `Object Invalid Value`

and some times it returns
error `Object Missing a Required Value`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go back to facebook for developers. There is a new version of the JavaScript SDK... you're probably using 2.6 it's at 2.7 right now. Just click on the "Get Code" again and make sure the SDK that's on your site matches up with the SDK that pops up on Facebook for developers. I fixed this issue for myself last night. Let me know if that doesn't fix your issue, I'm currently working on a blog post about this very issue.

Your Version:
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6";

New Version:
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7";

Comment: If you're using the iframe... make sure the iframe on your website matches up with the iframe that facebook provides.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer did not rectify my problem. I do not get the "Object Invalid Value" error anymore. The problem seemed that I was using dynamic content. What I did was:

1. Change the url in the data-href attribute to the full url of the page containing the facebook comment plugin box. Do not include any query strings eg. ?product=1. Only the page url.
2. Add the following script code to the page:

   ```
   <script>
   $(".fb-comments").attr("data-href", window.location.href);
   </script>
   ```

   It works. See screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. It solved just ensure two things.

1. In header section:

   ```
   <meta property="og:url" content="CURRENT PAGE URL"/>
   ```
2. In comment section:

   ```
   <div class="fb-comments"
      data-href="CURRENT PAGE URL"
      data-numposts="10"
      data-width="100%">
   </div>
   ```

You can set the "CURRENT PAGE URL" using javaScript (follow the previous answer) or any server side script.
In PHP it would be.

```
<?php
      echo  (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : 
      "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
?>
```